# Set width of table grid in percentage bases on range slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, rangeslider

I want to set the width of table column based on the range slider value using jQuery.There are multiple range slider can be seen in this [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc4Mb.png). If the value of first range slider is 21% then the width of first column in table must be 21%. Similarly, if the value of second range slider is 16% then the width of second column in table must be 16%.

Secondly, if i move to first range slider and the value of first range slider will be increased. if value of first slider increase then it must decrease the value of second slider. Means, I want to keep the value of all the slider 100%;

Please check below code

```css
    thead tr {
        background: blue;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .main-div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .rannge-slider-container {
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .table-container {
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="rannge-slider-container">
        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">19</span>
        </div>

        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">16</span>
        </div>
        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">6</span>
        </div>
        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">13</span>
        </div>
        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">13</span>
        </div>
        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">13</span>
        </div>
        <div class="range-slider">
            <input class="range-slider1" type="range" value="14" min="0" max="20">
            <span class="range-slider__value">20</span>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <!-- end slider html-->
    <div class="table-container">
        <table class="dgrid-row-table" role="presentation">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Date</th>
                    <th>Activity</th>
                    <th>
                        Activity</th>
                    <th>
                        Qty
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Rate
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Amount
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        SKU
                    </th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        12/01/2016
                    </td>
                    <td> Item name </td>
                    <td>
                        Description of the item </td>
                    <td>
                        2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        225.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        450.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        PRD123
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        12/01/2016
                    </td>
                    <td> Item name </td>
                    <td>
                        Description of the item </td>
                    <td>
                        2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        225.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        450.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        PRD123
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anybody please help me how i can do it.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post some code that you tried. w/o that no clue what you are asking

Comment: @joyBlanks code added in my question